# Каким образом можно уникализировать вывод из БД?

Tags: python, алгоритм, django, postgresql, orm

Имеется таблица сообщений следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос заключается в том, каким образом на основе этой таблицы вывести список диалогов.
Список диалогов имеет следующие требования:

1. Пользователь не может видеть самого себя в этом списк
2. Юзернейм собеседника не должен дублирваться.

Первый пункт криво-косо я реализовал, а вот на втором очень сильно застрял.

```
# model
# Получаем список всех диалогов пользователя (фильтруем по двум полям сразу)
dialogs = DialogModel.objects.filter(Q(u_from=u_id) | Q(u_to=u_id))
for dialog in dialogs:
    # Не допускает, чтобы пользователь видел самого себя в диалогах
    dialog.user = dialog.u_from
    if dialog.u_from_id == self.u_id:
         dialog.user = dialog.u_to

# template
# Просто вывод сообщений, на всякий случай
{% for dialog in dialogs %}
    {{ dialog.user }} {{ dialog.time }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

На текущий момент результат выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако нужно, чтобы никнейм повторялся только единожды для отдельного собеседника.
Каким образом и на каком этапе можно это реализовать?

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить, если следующее сообщение от того же самого адресата, то не указывать dialog.user.

Ваш пример в который я добавил непроверенный псевдо-код:

```
# model
# Получаем список всех диалогов пользователя (фильтруем по двум полям сразу)
dialogs = DialogModel.objects.filter(Q(u_from=u_id) | Q(u_to=u_id))
i = 0
for dialog in dialogs:
    # Не допускает, чтобы пользователь видел самого себя в диалогах
    dialog.user = dialog.u_from
    if dialog.u_from_id == self.u_id:
        dialog.user = dialog.u_to
    nextItemIndex = i + 1
    if dialogs.length >= nextItemIndex and dialogs[nextItemIndex].u_from_id != self.u_id:
        dialog.user = ''
    i = nextItemIndex

# template
# Просто вывод сообщений, на всякий случай
{% for dialog in dialogs %}
    {{ dialog.user }} {{ dialog.time }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено:

```
# Получаем таблицу сообщений пользователя
dialogs = DialogModel.objects.filter(Q(u_from=u_id) | Q(u_to=u_id))

# Превращаем QuerySet в список словарей
dialogs = dialogs.values('u_from__id', 'u_from__username', 'u_to__id', 'u_to__username', 'time')

# Делаем так, чтобы не видеть самого себя в списках диалогах
# Так же это можно реализовать через сравнение в шаблоне (это будет даже короче по коду),
# но я решил оставить эту логику во вьюхе и не раскидывать логику по всему проекту
for dialog in dialogs:
    dialog['username'] = dialog.pop('u_from__username')
    dialog['id'] = dialog.pop('u_from__id')
    if dialog['id'] == self.u_id:
        dialog['username'] = dialog.pop('u_to__username')
        dialog['id'] = dialog.pop('u_to__id')

# На выходе получаем список словарей с содержимым, вроде
# {'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 23, 16, 47, 37, 600365), 'username': 'Гость13', 'id': 13}

# Так как в списке могут попадаться словари с одинаковым username, то удаляем дубликаты
dialogs = list({item['username']: item for item in dialogs}.values())

# В результате получаем список словарей без повторяющихся username, готовых к выводу
```